# How get get xargs to split string to lines?

Tags: linux, bash

Can someone explain why the below

```
$ echo $a
1 2 3
$ echo $a | xargs -n1 -I{} echo {}
1 2 3
```

isn't outputted as?

```
1
2
3
```

I would like to end up with

```
cp 1 1.old
cp 2 2.old
cp 3 3.old
```

and understand how `-I` works in `xargs` in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your question`-I` and `-n` cannot work together but if you put it separately, it can work

`a="1 2 3"; echo $a | xargs -n1 | xargs -I{} echo cp {} {}.old`

Comment: Why use `xargs | xargs` if it can be done in a [single `xargs`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68453524/548225)

Comment: @anubhava There are many ways to get it expected. It's just preference.  In this case the OP likes  `echo` :).

Comment: `xargs -I{} echo cp {} {}.old <<< "${a// /$'\n'}` doesn't even require any pipeline or `echo/printf`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `printf | xargs`:

```sh
a='1 2 3'
printf '%s\n' $a | xargs -I{} echo cp {} {}.old
```

Once satisfied with the output, you can remove `echo` before `cp`.

or else, without using `printf`, you can do this in `xargs` only:

```sh
xargs -I{} echo cp {} {}.old <<< "${a// /$'\n'}

cp 1 1.old
cp 2 2.old
cp 3 3.old
```

---

Here is a pure bash way of doing this:

```sh
for v in $a; do
   echo cp "$v" "$v.old"
done
```

Comment: Wouldn't `for v in $a` make more sense in the last example? The variable can't contain any whitespace or shell metacharacters, but that horse has already bolted anyway.

Comment: @anubhava: I can understand why the OP's code does not work and yours does. What is still a mystery, is that the seemingly similar `echo $a | xargs -n1 echo` **does** output each number in a separate line. After all, it also should expand into a single `echo 1 2 3`, isn't it?

Comment: @tripleee: Yes I agree with you. (modified)

Comment: @user1934428: Yes `xargs -n1` does output on separate lines because `xargs` runs only one `echo` per argument. But issue is that we cannot use `{}` with that to form `cp` command.

Comment: Ah, I now see in the man page in the explanation for `-I`: _Also, unquoted blanks do not  terminate input items; instead the separator is the newline character._ I think this is what the original attempt makes it fail! Perhaps this could be added to your answer, in particular as the OP explicitly asks for an explanation why her solution does not work.